# Is there a way to find max values of three column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been working on a project which analyze credit rate from different bank.
I have a simple table structured like below

```sql
    `id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `credit_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `credit_name2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `rate_home` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `rate_vehicle` float NOT NULL,
    `rate_need` float NOT NULL,
    `bankname` float NOT NULL,
```

Example input below:

| id | credit_name | credit_name2 | rate_home | rate_vehicle | rate_need | bankname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Take Me | Take Me 2 | 10 | 5 | 15 | Bank A |
| 2 | Take Me | Take Me 2 | 15 | 20 | 8 | Bank B |
| 3 | Take Me | Take Me 2 | 20 | 25 | 45 | Bank C |
| 4 | Take Me | Take Me 2 | 35 | 12 | 4 | Bank D |
| 5 | GET Me | GET Me 2 | 11 | 6 | 12 | Bank A |
| 6 | GET Me | GET Me 2 | 15 | 45 | 23 | Bank B |
| 7 | GET Me | GET Me 2 | 22 | 67 | 35 | Bank C |
| 8 | GET Me | GET Me 2 | 36 | 6 | 7 | Bank D |

Example output:

| rate_home | rate_vehicle | rate_need |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35 from bank d | 25 from bank c | 45 from bank c |
| 36 from bank d | 67 from bank c | 45 from bank c |

The output may be a wrong structure bu forgive my lack of experience.
Every 4 rows must be compared in itself
I use BS4 TO fetch data , MYSQL to store the data  and PYTHON to process data

Comment: To be clear, you want the max value for each rate* column and the corresponding bankname?

Comment: What about ties? What if there are two banks with rate_home = 35 for instance? Please show the desired result for this case, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy solution but you can use union for the 3 columns , then use an outer query to get the 1 result for each column:

```
select max(rate_home) as rate_home,max(rate_vehicle) as rate_vehicle, max(rate_need) as rate_need
from (   
SELECT  concat(t1.rate_home,' from ', t1.bankname) as rate_home ,
        null as rate_vehicle,
        null as rate_need
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.rate_home < t2.rate_home
WHERE t2.rate_home IS NULL
union
SELECT  null as rate_home,
        concat(t1.rate_vehicle,' from ', t1.bankname) as rate_vehicle ,
         null as rate_need
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.rate_vehicle < t2.rate_vehicle
WHERE t2.rate_vehicle IS NULL
union
SELECT  null as rate_home,
        null as rate_vehicle,
        concat(t1.rate_need,' from ', t1.bankname) as rate_need 
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.rate_need < t2.rate_need
WHERE t2.rate_need IS NULL ) as tbl;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/0WlUbzT1

*Note* this doesn't handle ties

**Edit**.The op needs the max values for each credit_name group. The above query helped the op and it's a slight modification from
[Slava Rozhnev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770171/is-there-a-way-to-find-max-values-of-three-column-in-mysql/73770701#73770701) answer

```
with `highest` as (
    select credit_name,
           max(`rate_home`) `max_rate_home`,
           max(`rate_vehicle`) `max_rate_vehicle`,
           max(`rate_need`) `max_rate_need`
   from `bank_rate`
    group by credit_name
) select highest.credit_name ,
         group_concat(distinct `max_rate_home`, ' at ', `lh`.`bankname`) `max_rate_home`,
         group_concat(distinct `max_rate_vehicle`, ' at ', `lv`.`bankname`) `max_rate_vehicle`,
         group_concat(distinct `max_rate_need`, ' at ', `ln`.`bankname`) `max_rate_need`
  from `highest`
  join `bank_rate` `lh` on `lh`.`rate_home` = `max_rate_home`
  join `bank_rate` `lv` on `lv`.`rate_vehicle` = `max_rate_vehicle`
  join `bank_rate` `ln` on `ln`.`rate_need` = `max_rate_need`
  group by highest.credit_name;
```

Comment: Thank you this solved this question. But there is something else which i forgot to ask

Comment: Think about this 4 rows is calculate 1 credit. And there are 10 or 100 credit names .
I updated dbfiddle.uk link with some data

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in next way:

- first get min of each of rates
- second self joins

```sql
with `lowest` as (
  select 
    min(`rate_home`) `lowest_home`, 
    min(`rate_vehicle`) `lowest_vehicle`, 
    min(`rate_need`) `lowest_need`
  from `rates`
) select
    concat(`lowest_home`, ' at ', `lh`.`bankname`) `lowest_home`,
    concat(`lowest_vehicle`, ' at ', `lv`.`bankname`) `lowest_vehicle`,
    concat(`lowest_need`, ' at ', `ln`.`bankname`) `lowest_need`
from `lowest`
join `rates` `lh` on `lh`.`rate_home` = `lowest_home`
join `rates` `lv` on `lv`.`rate_vehicle` = `lowest_vehicle`
join `rates` `ln` on `ln`.`rate_need` = `lowest_need`;
```

[sqlize](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/c851546f9de17a8073968873be35c143/)

Result:

```
+=============+================+=============+
| lowest_home | lowest_vehicle | lowest_need |
+=============+================+=============+
| 1 at Bank A | 1 at Bank C    | 1 at Bank B |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks slava but i need max values. I try to change min to max but it returned 12 rows as result

Comment: @simsar, It happens when several banks offer same max value. Please look next modification https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/9b227458d629e7c879b229e619380355/

Answer (score 0):

this can be done in sql side

```
SELECT [Other Fields],
  (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (rate_home), (rate_vehicle), (rate_need)) AS value(v)) as [MaxRate]
FROM [YourTableName]
```

Comment: What is "v" in SELECT Max(v) ?

Comment: From value(v), "value" is the alias for the virtual table and "v" is the name of the virtual column of the rate values

Comment: since you in mysql, you can try this simple one:
SELECT GREATEST(col1, col2 ...) FROM table